# separating imageUp and text in ImageTextButton

Tags: libgdx

How does one set the spacing between an `imageUp` and `text` in `ImageTextButton.Style`? The default positioning looks like this

[image]

, but I would like to move the image more to the left while keeping text centered. Is such thing possible in libgdx?

Answer (score 1):

found one approach

```
imageTextButton.getImageCell().pad(//set padding);
```

or

```
imageTextButton.getLabelCell().pad(//set padding);
```